# defining a variable type using another dynamic variable. oracle. pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, sys-refcursor

Here is the deal I'm trying to define `MY_VARIABLE`, which would be of a type `MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE`.

The problem is that `MY_TABLE` is dynamic and i receive it as a `varchar2` variable, so something like

```
 TYPE my_variable 
   IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE;
```

wouldnt work because 
Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY DENNIS.XXPORTER

> 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' must name a table, cursor or cursor-variable

Now, how do i deal with that??

P S I need `my_variable` to fetch records from the `ref cursor`. And i used `ref cursor` not a `cursor` as i executed a query where table name (in `from clause`) was a variable

Comment: it's unclear if your input is a string or a refcursor.

Comment: my_table is of varchar2

Comment: then you cant create a rowtype using only the name of the table (unless you write dynamic plsql code - which i'm guessing would be an overkill here). if you have a ref cursor you can just iterate it.

Comment: Yeah, but where would i fetch the values to?

Comment: As with each loop - i'll have a number of values to be stored. What variable/variables can i use for that? AND  i do not know the table name or columns types in advance

Comment: this is the problem with ref cursors - you cant really use them if you don't define a structure. maybe try to be more specific about the problem you are facing and we will try to suggest better way's of dealing with it.

Comment: the guy below Justin Cave  is just about right when implying what the problem is. Im currently reading about dbms_Sql package. I ll post any updates regarding what i've found out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare a variable whose data type is not known until runtime.

If you are trying to use dynamic SQL where the structure of the result set is also dynamic (if the number of columns and their data types are fixed for any table that is passed in, you could statically declare a record variable of an appropriate type), then you would realistically need to use the [`DBMS_SQL` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm) to execute the statement, to gather data about the columns that are returned, and to bind appropriate variables into which you could fetch the data.

You can see an example of using the `DBMS_SQL` package in Tom Kyte's [`dump_csv` function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:68212348056) that dumps the results of an arbitrary SQL statement to a file.

Comment: thanks, Your answer is quite useful. Currently im eximining the dbms_sql package.

Comment: that was it. THe example of a solution is somewhere on askTom website. I'll add a link sometime

Comment: @Dennis - Other than the link I had originally?  Or are you saying you prefer an example other than the `dump_csv` procedure?

Comment: Oh, my bad :) Justin, the link you initially posted ( the dump_csv one) is the one i mentioned. For some reason i didnt notice it the first time I read your answer, so I wasted some time looking for the same info myself :)